# Need help on Incompatible types, Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment Found: com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.AllUsersFragment

Tags: android

*I have two classes, MainActivity.java and AllUsersFragment.java and the incompatible types error occurred in MainActivity.java which has a reference to AllUsersFragment.java class.*

```
package com.journaldev.navigationdrawer;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
Toolbar toolbar;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);




    setupToolbar();

    DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[2];

    //drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.connect, "Connect");
    drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.fixtures, "All Users");
    drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.table, "Add User");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setupDrawerToggle();


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.journaldev.navigationdrawer/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.journaldev.navigationdrawer/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment =  new AllUsersFragment();
```

**The AllUsersFragment is where the incompatible types error occurred.**

```
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new AddUsersFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new TableFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

void setupDrawerToggle() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state change.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

}

```
package com.journaldev.navigationdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AllUsersFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
InputStream inputstream;
BufferedReader reader;
String m;
String name;
String age;
String title;
ListView list;
List<Map<String, String>> data;
JSONArray jsonArray;
JSONObject jsonObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle s) {
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_allusers);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnparse);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    try {
        inputstream = getResources().getAssets().open("json.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
        m = reader.toString();
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        m = total.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(AllUsersFragment.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(m);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Names");
                int arraylength = jsonArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
                    Map<String, String> moviemap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = jsonChildNode.optString("Name").toString();
                    age = jsonChildNode.optString("Age").toString();
                    moviemap.put("A", name);
                    moviemap.put("B", age);
                    data.add(moviemap);
                }
                String[] from = {"A", "B"};
                int[] views = {R.id.lblmoviename, R.id.lblcategory};
                final SimpleAdapter myadapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllUsersFragment.this, data, R.layout.jslist, from, views);
                list.setAdapter(myadapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


    public AllUsersFragment() {

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allusers, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
public class AllUsersFragment extends AppCompatActivity
```

for this one:

```
public class AllUsersFragment extends Fragment
```

And make sure the Fragment class you are importing is from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Thank you, while it solved that error, I have more errors occurring such as cannot resolve setContentView, findViewById and getMenuInflater. Are there any alternative to these methods ?